# Wordpress Advanced Custom Fields in Widgets

Tags: wordpress, widget, advanced-custom-fields

I am unable to retrieve the values entered into the Advanced Custom Fields in a widget.

I am following the documentation [written here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get-values-widget/), but not having any luck.

This is my set up.

Under wordpress `appearance / widgets` in the wordpress dashboard I have added a `sidebar navigation` widget to `Footer 1`.  That sidebar navigation contains a `footer_column` which is an `advanced custom field`.

[image]

Then in my themes `footer.php` I am trying to access the values entered into that field, but unfortunately it returns `NULL` all the time.

For example I have tried this code:

```
 <!-- Footer 1 Widget -->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
          <?php if (is_active_sidebar('footer-1')) : ?>
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('footer-1'); ?>
            
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : 
                the_post();
                var_dump(the_field('footer_column', 'widget_' . 'sidebar-navigation-2'));
                
                endwhile ?>
          <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Both with and without `the_post()` loop

**** UPDATE *****

On further inspection I believe that the problem is being caused because the values being entered into the wordpress widget on the wordpress dashboard are not being persisted.

After adding a link to the repeater field in the widget and submitting using `ADD Link` whenever I navigate to another part of the dashboard I am shown a message that there is unsaved data.   When I leave the page `appearance/widget` and return I can see that the previously added links are not being persisted and the widget is empty.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that on Wordpress Admin -> Appearance -> Widgets -> Edit Widget Content was not displaying a `Save` button.  I looked at the Css and the CSS was set to `display: none` for the form controls on the widget.

I changed the widget type to `Block` and then the `Save` button appeared and I was able to persist the ACF data

So the answer is that the widget `Sidebar-Navigation` was not persisting and hence `get_field()` was always going to return `NULL`